# How to prevent user to access website by IP address

Tags: django

I have a django website, which can be accessed by, such as 'www.mysite.com'. And the site's IP is: 33.33.33.33.

By entering 33.33.33.33, the website does work.

Is it possible to disable the access by 33.33.33.33? I only want 'www.mysite.com' to work.

Comment: That's not possible because the IP is required for the hostname to resolve.

Comment: The site shown under that domain is set as default site in the webserver. That’s has to be corrected in your webserver settings and not in django.

Comment: @tryingtogethelp the IP is for sure required to communicate with the server. But the website could be configured so that it will only display a site if the `Host` header is sent with the client request (or as part of the URL in case of HTTP/1.0) and that's most likely what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might do it in server settings. For example suppose your server is Apache2, then you might add the following directives (as per the documentation here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) and restart your server. In the below example, access will be blocked for 10.252.46.165 IP address. Please note the order of directives/statements are often important. Please make sure you read the docs carefully.

```
<RequireAll> 
    Require all granted 
    Require not ip 10.252.46.165 
</RequireAll>
```

If it is nginx server, you may want to read this link (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/#restrict) carefully.

They have given an example where they restrict the ip 192.168.1.2. See below but make sure you understand each directive in the documentation above.

```
stream {
...
    server {
                 listen 12345;
                 deny 192.168.1.2;
                 allow 192.168.1.1/24;
                 allow 2001:0db8::/32;
                 deny all;
                 }
}
```

Please read in documentation, what does each section do **and it will be important the order in which you type the statements**. So please read carefully.

Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I am using nginx. How to do it. Thank you so much for your replay.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the section for nginx.